# How to use dictinct to get single record in many to one relation ship mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 2 tables like

```
      user                         user_address
user_id  name           user_address_id   city   user_id    address_type
   1     abc                 1             AAA      1         PRESENT
                             2             AAA      1         PERMANANT
```

I need query like

```
select user model1 , user_address model2 where model1.user_id = distinct model2.user_id
```

Because i know both addresses are same so  i need only once.How i can get only one address.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

try put "group by" for a field on user_address, if they are the same anyway

```
select * from user_address inner join user as u on user_id = u.user_id group by city;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what you need you can try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        city ,
        address_type
    FROM
        user_address
    GROUP BY
        user_id

) as tmp
INNER JOIN user
    ON user.user_id = tmp.user_id
```